# How do you echo a variable from a function outside the public http folder?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to make a registration form, but i would like to do that with ajax. I made a script where i want to echo the output of the registration function, which is in an includes folder outside of the public html folder. The output should be alerted, but when i click the button, the alert box is empty. How should i fix this?

forms.js:

```
function realtimeverwerking(view, voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, email, wachtwoord, bevestiging, dag, maand, jaar, sport, captcha){
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: 'registreerverwerking.php',
        data: {view: view, voornaam: voornaam, tussenvoegsel: tussenvoegsel, achternaam: achternaam, email: email, wachtwoord: wachtwoord,
            bevestiging: bevestiging, dag: dag, maand: maand, jaar: jaar, sport: sport, captcha: captcha},
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

registreerverwerking.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['captcha'])){
    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

    // als captcha niet is ingevoerd hoeft de rest van de code niet uitgevoerd te worden
    if(!$captcha)
    {
        echo "Voltooi de captcha.";
    }
    else
    {
        include_once '/home/6V_Ramon_1516/Includes/algemenefuncties.php';

        registreren();
    }
}
```

(a part of) registreren():

```
if (empty($bericht)) {      
        // some code where i check stuff, $bericht should say a user already exists

    }
    else{
        return $bericht;
    }
```

Comment: Check the Network tab of the browser console, to see if the AJAX call is returning successfully. And check the PHP error log on the server to see if there's any problem when the script runs.

Comment: ajax call is succesfully tested, it will alert that the captcha isnt set, but the alert box stays empty when it calls the function

Comment: Are you sure `$bericht` is set?

Comment: i am very sure! before i decided to add ajax $bericht was set, but in an annoying way, so hence ajax. im using the same email as in the database so it should say the user already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you do

```
return $bericht;
```

Either that needs to be an echo, or you need to capture that return when you call the function registreren(); a la

```
$return = registreren();
```

and then do an

```
echo $return;
```

In order for $bericht to be sent back to your javascript in the form of the "data" variable.

Comment: Thank you for looking at the code, but the alert box is still empty

Comment: If `$bericht` is set correctly inside the function, then this answer should work.

Comment: so problem was: i uploaded the file into the wrong folder. problem solved thank you!